# Splunk with ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, splunk

I am having a problem with configuring Splunk to send logs on ECS Cluster.
From the event tab in service, this error was there 
Problem Statement: unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance xxxx is missing an attribute required by your task.
after doing a deep drive I found have to update /etc/ecs/ecs.config. and entry echo ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS='["splunk","awslogs"]'.
But this couldn't help?
still getting the same error.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Avik, not really an answer to your question, but we have a very simple way how to get logs and metrics from ECS clusters to Splunk Enterprise and Splunk Cloud https://www.outcoldsolutions.com/blog/2018-03-15-monitoring-aws-ecs-in-splunk/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send container logs to Splunk. you need to have logConfiguration tag in task definition json with all required details like below

{
"log-driver": "splunk",
"log-opts": {
"splunk-token": "",
"splunk-url": "",
...
}
}

[AWS task definition parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_storage)
[splunk logging options](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/)

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways by creating a task definition as follows:    {
 "containerDefinitions": [{
  "name": "auth",
  "image": "srirajan/auth",
  "cpu": 512,
  "memory": 512,
  "portMappings": [{
   "protocol": "tcp",
   "containerPort": 10080,
   "hostPort": 0
  }],
  "logConfiguration": {
   "logDriver": "splunk",
   "options": {
    "splunk-token": "xxxxx",
    "splunk-url": "xxxx",
    "splunk-insecureskipverify": "true",
    "splunk-format": "json"
   }
  },
  "essential": true,
  "dockerLabels": {
   "service": "auth"
  }
 }],
 "family": "auth"
}

Comment: then by updating the user data as follows :#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS='["splunk","awslogs"]' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config. But no luck still getting the same error service service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 4aa20602-2ca8-421f-aad3-dbce7ced2445 is missing an attribute required by your task.

Comment: Is your ec2 added to your ECS cluster ? You must have another entry in  user data to attach your ec2 to ECS cluster. We missed this many times so just want to make sure .

Comment: Where is your docker image ? I can see srirajan/auth in your task json but it neither points to docker hub/ecr repository.

Comment: If you can help me how to add it. i am trying to send ECS cluster logs to Splunk Enterprise.But keep on getting the error missing attributes.If you can share some doc or any link to get this thing done will be really helpful.

Comment: Yes i have changed it to stripathiopstree i.e my docker repo. but it's not helpful

Comment: Yes the app is working fine without splunk integration